# How the parabola can pass the most int-points?

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

> Give a coordinate paper, just use $8 \times 8$ squares($9 \times 9$ lines), we call the crossing of lines are int-points.
>
> Now draw a parabola, how it can pass the most int-points?

I know, when the style is $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, the $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+1$ can pass $8$ int-points, it is the most. but if rotation the parabola, how to do it?

Comment: I tried with a 45° rotated parabola and found several passing through 8 int-points, but not more.

Comment: @Aretino Thank you for your attention. I find the $((x+3)+y)=((x+3)-y)^2$, here $x \in [-4,4], y \in [-1,7]$, and it just pass $7$ int-points. could you show the $45^\circ$ rotated equation please? And I do not know how to prove the general situation.

Comment: Parabolas given by the equation $(x-y)^2=a(x+y)+b$ pass through 8 int-points for $(a,b)$ equal to $(3,-2)$, $(3,-8)$, as well as their "specular" companions $(-3,46)$ and $(-3,40)$.

Comment: @Aretino Thank you. now I think, maybe it can be based on the exhaustive method, find all the parabolas, but not prove.

Comment: @xunitc: I find this question interesting, but before investing a lot of time on it, I'd like to know: Is this an exercise (say, from a textbook or competition) with a known answer? Do we have any reason to believe that there's a cleverer approach than exhaustion?

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your attention. This is a high school entrance examination question. it is a  choice question, the answer is $8$. For middle school students, maybe only care $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ style. But I think we should also look at other parabolas.